# How error handling is done in Backbone.js save()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model. Now I want to update the model on server side, so I call *model.save();* now as backbone.js makes an ajax call to server with PUT request. If the server fails to process this request, it sends some error code to client.

Now my question is, client has model's updated state, and server has an old state, both are inconsistent. Now on *error()* callback of my *model.save()* I want to revert the model to old state, how would I do it? Does backbone keeps copy of old state with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
oldMOdel = newModel.previousAttributes();
```

check out [this](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previousAttributes)